# turn answer into comment

Tags: support, comments, flagging, answers

[This question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/how-does-the-crew-address-the-captain-in-das-boot) has a new comment by [Alper](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/9273/alper). As far as I remember this comment has been an answer before.

For my own answers I could, from 50 rep onwards, make such a transition myself: delete my answer and post a new comment. But who is able to do this for other users's answers? Is there a function for direct transformation? What is the recommended action if I think this should be done, but do not have enough reputation to do it myself - flag the answer for moderator attention? And will the user in question get a message for explanation? I mean - it could be a bit puzzling to learn "Thank you for A, but you should have done B, which however you are not allowed to do, so we did it for you."

Comment: @Takkat Sorry, I didn't know. Would it be feasible to mention this request on http://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ? I believe this could help avoiding such a mistake. Anyway, I translated my question.

Comment: like this http://german.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers?

Comment: @Takkat The page that I linked to explains that questions in both English and German are welcome. I wanted to suggest to add that this does not extend to the meta site. (Because I thought that German posts are ok everywhere on German Language SE after reading this.) I don't see how your link is related to this, but maybe you meant something else?

Comment: Ah I see now... good idea, I edited that in. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we see an answer which is wrong, misleading, just a copy of an existing answer, or not an answer at all, we have the option to:

- edit it to improve it.
- [downvote](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) it. *(requires 125 reputation on a beta site)*
- vote to [delete](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) it. *(requires downvotes and 4k reputation on beta sites)*
- Flag it for moderator attention for deletion or conversion to a comment.

It happens quite often that unregistered or low rep users who are not able to [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) everywhere (*>50 rep.*) post a comment or a question as an answer. These posts will be deleted or converted to a comment on request, or after we had received a moderator flag.

Sometimes a system-wide robot (Community Moderator) will cast a flag on low qualtiy post which then will put them in the review queue for us to decide further actions.

Also see:

- [What posts should be flagged for deletion?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/661/what-posts-should-be-flagged-for-deletion)

Sometimes such posts will not add any value to a question. These posts may be deleted without conversion to a comment. In the example you mentioned this could be debated, as we already have an accepted answer saying the same.

Comment: I'd love to see you mention the NAA-flag, which is the "proper" action to take as low-rep-user